# Post request not getting sent with Angular.js. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, model-view-controller, http-post

So im trying to get a name with a click from the client, and send the name ( which i changed to json in order to actually be able to send the info) it to the server . Right now the server sends it back, and the client posts it to the index page (which im doing just so i can see the data that the server is getting). When i see the data its showing up as [object Object]. So Something is going wrong, im hoping someone can help me out.

index.html

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr ng-repeat="contact in databases.databases">
    <td>{{ contact.name }} <button type="button"ng-click="addContactlist(contact.name)">Click Me</button></td>
    <td>{{ contact.sizeOnDisk }} </td>
    <td>{{ contact.empty }} </td>
  </tr>
  </table> 

DB name clicked: <p ng-bind="DB_NAME"></p>
</div>

</body>
```

client.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("controller connected");

function refresh(){ 
// create contacklist route 
$http.get('/databases').success(function(response) {
    console.log("recived data requested");
    $scope.databases = response; 
  });
}

// Call refresh to init cantacklist 
refresh(); 


// add Doc to table 
$scope.addContactlist = function(contactItem) {
  alert("Working ");
    $http.post('/collection', JSON.stringify({'contactItem': contactItem})).success(function(response) {
      $scope.DB_NAME = response ; 
      });
    console.log("posted: "+contactItem);
  };




});// Controller
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path'); //core module 
var databaseUrl = "localhost:27017/DB"; // default env
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    assert = require('assert');

//configure app
var app = express(); 
var db = new Db('DB', new Server('localhost', 27017));


db.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('database error', err)
}); 

db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
}); 

// store all html files in views 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
// parses recived json input 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// store all js in Scripts folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));

// Technology not needed but good practice, especailly when serval people are working on it 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
}); 

// listen for contactlist get request, aka transfers the contacklist in mongo to client
app.get('/databases', function (req, res) {
    console.log("-- recived GET request --"); 
    db.open(function(err, db) {

      // Use the admin database for the operation
      var adminDb = db.admin();

      // List all the available databases
      adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);
        console.log(dbs);
        res.json(dbs); 
        db.close();
      });
    });
}); 

// listen for contactlist get request
app.post('/collection', function (req, res) {
    console.log("-- recived collection post request --"); 
    console.log('req ' + req.body);
    res.json(req.body);

    db.open(function(err, db) {
         // Grab a collection without a callback no safe mode
         // once request is working will switch to re.body
        var col1 = db.collection('DB');
    });
}); 



// Implement a web server to listen to requests 
app.listen(4444, function(){
    console.log('ready on port 4444'); 
});
```

[image]

With fix

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is an object, try this:

```
DB name clicked: <p ng-bind="DB_NAME | json"></p>
```

`json` filter converts the object in JSON notation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json

Comment: I just want the second object. How do i do that ?

Comment: What second object...?

Comment: I dont want to send  {contactItem: "Name"}), i just want the "Name" .

Comment: Can you post what your output is? How can I know it?

Comment: So, `<p ng-bind="DB_NAME.contactItem">`

Comment: Well yeah. But thats just for visual. Im trying to just send the "Name" to the server.js from the client.js. I cant just type req.contactItem. Once i get that working im going to set up a new Datatbase with that "Name".

Comment: `$http.post('/collection', {'contactItem': contactItem})` and you will find it server side as `req.body.contactItem`

Comment: req.body.contactItem. Works

Comment: Yep, glad you did it.

Comment: lol yeah thanks, i guess i could just do req.body.contactItem afterall

Comment: don't forget you can format things in your controller $scope.anything = JSON.parse(json-result);